# Rearrange buttons based on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have four buttons or simple `div` with clickable links.

On home page, the order is `A-B-C-D`. If you are on `B` page, then the order of the button changes to `B-A-C-D`. If you are on `C` page, then the order changes to `C-A-B-D`. You can see it in the picture below.

[image]

Now, I can simply make four sets of buttons and put condition logic to it but that seems like a bad idea as there will be lots of redundancy.

What would be a good way to rearrange these `buttons` or `div` based on what page the user is in? (Of course, it will apply to child pages, such as .com/b/more).

EDIT:

So far, it is simply four simple `div` as shown below.

```
 <?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
    <div id="d">D</div>
 <?php } elseif ( is_page('b') ){ ?>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
    <div id="d">D</div>
 <?php } elseif ( is_page('c') ){ ?>
    <div id="c">C</div>
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="d">D</div>
 <?php } elseif ( is_page('d') ){ ?>
    <div id="d">D</div>
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: show us the code that you're trying with....

Comment: So far, it is literally simple four `div` with some `id` and `classes`. I will update the question.

Comment: So find the element, remove it, append it to the front of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, using plain JavaScript, is:

```
// using Immediately-Invoked Function Expression,
// not entirely necessary, but it keeps everything
// contained:
(function prefaceWith(suppliedPathName) {

  // the potential 'valid' values for the ids,
  // I'd prefer to get this list dynamically,
  // using some form of attribute-selector:
  var valid = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],

    // if we have a 'suppliedPathName' then we get
    // the second character ('1'), the first
    // character of a pathName is the '/';
    // otherwise we use the default first-value from
    // the array of valid values:
    id = suppliedPathName ? suppliedPathName.charAt(1) : valid[0],

    // if the retrieved 'id' is present in the array of valid
    // values we retrieve the element with that 'id', otherwise
    // we get the element with id of the first valid value:
    elem = valid.indexOf(id) > -1 ? document.getElementById(id) : document.getElementById(valid[0]),

    // retrieving the parent of the found element:
    parent = elem.parentNode;

  // inserting the found element before the current
  // first-child of the parent:
  parent.insertBefore(elem, parent.firstChild);

// passing in the current pathName to the function:
})(window.location.pathName);
```

```js
(function prefaceWith(suppliedPathName) {

  var valid = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    id = suppliedPathName ? suppliedPathName.charAt(1) : valid[0],
    elem = valid.indexOf(id) > -1 ? document.getElementById(id) : document.getElementById(valid[0]),
    parent = elem.parentNode;

  parent.insertBefore(elem, parent.firstChild);


})(window.location.pathName);
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#a {
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  background-color: green;
}
#c {
  background-color: blue;
}
#d {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
<div id="d">d</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vt3t0awz/1/), for experimentation/development.

To demonstrate the dynamic selection I've given the 'valid' `<div>` elements a custom `data-*` attribute, in this case: `data-button`, by which they will be selected when the function runs.

Note that I've deliberately omitted the `data-button` attribute for the element of `id="a"`, giving this HTML:

```
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b" data-button>b</div>
<div id="c" data-button>c</div>
<div id="d" data-button>d</div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
(function prefaceWith(suppliedPathName) {

  // This line is the only change, here we're using
  // Array.prototype.map(), with Function.prototype.call(),
  // to convert the NodeList result of document.querySelector()
  // into an array of the 'id's of the <div> elements with
  // the 'data-button' attribute we used to select:
  var valid = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-button]'), function(div) {

      // returning the element's 'id':
      return div.id;
    }),
    id = suppliedPathName ? suppliedPathName.charAt(1) : valid[0],
    elem = valid.indexOf(id) > -1 ? document.getElementById(id) : document.getElementById(valid[0]),
    parent = elem.parentNode;

  parent.insertBefore(elem, parent.firstChild);


})(window.location.pathName);
```

```js
(function prefaceWith(suppliedPathName) {

  var valid = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-button]'), function(div) {
      return div.id;
    }),
    id = suppliedPathName ? suppliedPathName.charAt(1) : valid[0],
    elem = valid.indexOf(id) > -1 ? document.getElementById(id) : document.getElementById(valid[0]),
    parent = elem.parentNode;

  parent.insertBefore(elem, parent.firstChild);


})(window.location.pathName);
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#a {
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  background-color: green;
}
#c {
  background-color: blue;
}
#d {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b" data-button>b</div>
<div id="c" data-button>c</div>
<div id="d" data-button>d</div>
```

Because 'A' is no longer a valid 'button,' the `<div>` of `id="b"` becomes the first automatically.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Conditional/ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).
- [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I will give it a try =) Thanks David

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I hope it's of some help to you! :)

Comment: It surely does! It was awesome with the description of what's going on =) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pathname to find the element to be targeted then

```js
jQuery(function(a) {
  var a = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
  //to test
  a = 'd/e';
  if (a) {
    var $el = $('#' + a.replace(/\//, '\\/'));
    $el.prependTo($el.parent())
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
  <div id="d/e">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just one gotcha in there: he mentions subpages, which would break the split-then-pop approach. I'd get the URI that comes right after the app's root (so if it's `www.example.com/myapp/d/more` you indexOf for `myapp` and then get a[i+1])